# Red Colored Tags Showing Up for Certain Tags and Questions is Confusing me. What do They Mean and Why are They Here?

Tags: support, tagging, asking-questions, meta, retagging

Status-byDesign and faq are both tags that appear completely red when one tries to view them or put them into a question Here is what I mean:

[image]

These appear to look like this because these tags are used quite frequently. However, this hypothesis seems to not be entirely true as many may be used not so much. The “status by design” tag only has 7 pages of answers as of when this question was posted.

As a follow up question, are there any other tag colors besides the basic blue one? This is all very fascinating to me. I have also linked down below two different colors. What does the gray one mean? This probably is for request questions such as the “support” tag and this question.

This is my first meta question! Please check out my other main account questions for who I am! Please give me feedback and correct me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [list of all of the tags](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags) can be found by clicking on the "Tags" link in the left-hand sidebar.  This link will take you to a directory of the tags used on the specific site or meta site which you are currently visiting.  The directory of tags used on Math Meta includes the following header:

[image]

Hovering over the red "moderator-only-tag" at the top brings up a message which indicates that red tags can only be added to a post by a moderator.

Comment: Thanks moderator, the grey required-tags then request service?

Comment: @TymaGaidash You can read the tag descriptions to see what they are for.

Comment: ♦︎ @XanderHenderson♦︎ Thanks for the help. I will get used to this.